# How do merge query results in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For example: there are products. Products have 4 different statuses.

I need query products from each status limit of 20. Results should be one array or collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and neat approach.

```
var filter = {
     $or:[
          {status: //your first status},
          {status: //your second status},
          {status: //your third status},
          {status: //your fourth status}
     ]
};

db.product_collection.find(filter, function(err, data){
     //your functionality
})
.exec()
.limit(20);
```

Hope this will help.